# linear algebra questions about matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a a matrix $X$ where 
$$
X=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & p(x) 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $p(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $3$ or 4 and different from $0$. I'm trying to find a matrix $S$ such that 
$$
S^{-1}XS=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1  \\
    -1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm not sure how to find $S$.. Any hints?

Comment: It may be impossible. If $p(x_0) = 0$, matrix $X$ isn't invertible, but $S^{-1}XS$ is.

Answer (score 12):

It is impossible to find what you seek.  The matrices $X$ and $S^{-1}XS$ are [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), and therefore have the same determinant.  The two determinants are $p(x)$ and $-1$, respectively.  Hence the only polynomial for which such an $S$ exists is the constant polynomial $p(x)=-1$; no polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ can work.

Comment: In the case $p(x)$=-1 how would we find $S$?

Comment: $S^{-1}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$; the columns are the eigenvectors of $X$.